# Using EF code-first migrations when design model is DB first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Real question seems to be here is which is the best way to refresh code first model from DB

Any downsides or alternatives how one could use code first migrations when domain model must reflect DB changes? (eg. in case MDS)

**Option 1:**
I have tried making POC of migration context is inherited from CodeFirstFromDB context directly.
When one generates EF model from Database the model is separated from migration context eg. dbcontext is not aware that such migrations exist. 
Migrations have been enabled for Migration Context only and therefore it will only track changes on it own resx.

```
public class MigrationInheritedDBContext : ModelCodeFirstFromDB 
{
    public MigrationInheritedDBContext() : base("name=MigrationInheritedDBContext ") 
{

    }
}




public partial class ModelCodeFirstFromDB : DbContext
{
    public ModelCodeFirstFromDB()
        : base("name=ModelCodeFirstFromDB")
    {
    }

    public ModelCodeFirstFromDB(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DMObject1> DMObject1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DMObject2> DMObject2 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DMObject3> DMObject3 { get; set; }
.
.
.
.
```

**Option 2:**
There are T4-templates that will generate db context directly from database.

Any notes, opinions, alternative approaches are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you want. Are you trying to establish initial code first models from an existing database and will then use a code first approach or are you trying to 'refresh' an existing code first model based on direct changes to the DB? If you are going to change your database first, then you should follow that workflow.

Comment: I would and my team would love to just use code first, but in some cases changes are coming from DB to model like Master Data Services or other product like data storage. Therefore I'm looking the best way to refresh from DB as well

Comment: With database first you can do a refresh that will update the partial classes. With code first I think the best you can do is reverse engineer the new or changed objects and then move them into your data and model projects. I used this technique to reverse engineer a large database piece by piece.